# what does the attribute selection in preprocess tab do in weka?

Tags: weka

I cant seem to find out what attribute selection filter does in pre process tab? someone could please tell me in simple language as im new to weka

when i apply it to my dataset it seems to remove a couple of attributes but im unsure why

Answer (score 1):

A real data set may contain many attributes. Applying any data mining process on this data set (e.g. finding clusters, generating a classification model ...) may take very long time.

Instead of that, we can select some attributes(dimensions) which is called `the most discriminative attributes`. These attributes can almost describe the data set with lower number of attributes and this will speed up any process done on the data.

Attribute selection tab contains many different methods for selecting these attributes. One of them is [CFS Feature Set Evaluation](http://www.opentox.org/dev/documentation/components/cfsfeatsel) This filter gives you the attributes that have higher correlation with the class label which makes them discriminative attributes.